# How to escape '&' ampersand in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping, ampersand

If you have maybe a code like this

```
set "CONTENT_LENGTH=24" & echo first=1&second=2&third=3
```

I want the echo to echo with the `&`

Comment: `echo first=1^&second=2^&third=3`

Comment: Just found it. ```set "CONTENT_LENGTH=24" & echo first=1^^^&second=2^^^&third=3```. My own wasn't working with the single and double quotes escapes maybe because I was using a PIPE. I used the triple ^ (hats) to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways you could do this.

**Escape characters**

In Windows batch files it seems to be the ^ character, so you'd just stick a ^ before your special character.

This page seems to cover the exceptions: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

On OS X/Linux, use backslashes: echo three\&four

**Wrap the parameter phrase in quotes.**

```
echo "three&four"
```

This should work on either system.